# Using Small (1-10 Items) Instance-Level Collections in Java

Tags: java, collections

While creating classes in Java I often find myself creating instance-level collections that I know ahead of time will be very small - less than 10 items in the collection. But I don't know the number of items ahead of time so I typically opt for a dynamic collection (ArrayList, Vector, etc).

```
class Foo
{
  ArrayList<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>(10);
}
```

A part of me keeps nagging at me that it's wasteful to use complex dynamic collections for something this small in size. Is there a better way of implementing something like this? Or is this the norm?

Note, I'm not hit with any (noticeable) performance penalties or anything like that. This is just me wondering if there isn't a better way to do things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `ArrayList` class in Java has only two data members, a reference to an `Object[]` array and a size—which you need anyway if you don't use an `ArrayList`. So the only advantage to not using an `ArrayList` is saving one object allocation, which is unlikely ever to be a big deal.

If you're creating and disposing of many, many instances of your container class (and by extension your `ArrayList` instance) every second, you *might* have a slight problem with garbage collection churn—but that's something to worry about if it ever occurs. Garbage collection is typically the least of your worries.

Comment: Current JVMs optimize heavily for object allocation and garbage collection concerns wrt to this are almost always unfounded.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of keeping things simple, I think this is pretty much a non-issue. Your implementation is flexible enough that if the requirements change in the future, you aren't forced into a refactoring. Also, adding more logic to your code for a hybrid solution just isn't worth it taking into account your small data set and the high-quality of Java's Collection API.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Collections](https://web.archive.org/web/20081018003459/http://google-collections.googlecode.com:80/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/package-summary.html) has collections optimized for immutable/small number of elements. See `Lists.asList` API as an example.

Answer (score 1):

The overhead is very small. It is possible to write a hybrid array list that has fields for the first few items, and then falls back to using an array for longer list.

You can avoid the overhead of the list object entirely by using an array. To go even further hardcore, you can declare the field as Object, and avoid the array altogether for a single item.

If memory really is a problem, you might want to forget about using object instances at the low-level. Instead use a larger data structure at a larger level of granularity.

Comment: Nothing that you're saying is wrong, per se, but I wouldn't want to do any of these things.  The complexity involved in somehow dynamically going between object -> array -> ArrayList is so great, and the cost of just creating a simple ArrayList so small, that I think this is just a bad sugges

Comment: It's rarely important, but when it is important it is fixable. For instance, javac does weird stuff to keep memory used by strings small, so we all benefit from faster, smaller compiles.